# top_up-min.js not available as gettopup.com website is down

Tags: javascript

I was using top_up-min.js for popups and was referring to the external site http://gettopup.com/releases/latest/top_up-min.js?libs=clip . Unfortunately the external website http://gettopup.com/ (the owner) is not available any more ( it might be mostly as part of discontinued heroku support for Legacy Routing).

Anyway does anyone has latest version of top_up-min.js ? If so kindly share the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you find a cached version of the page

[cached version](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NKOi3jr8Z-UJ:gettopup.com/documentation%20&cd=3&hl=de&ct=clnk&gl=de)

there you find the link to the [Github page with the source](https://github.com/archan937/topup/tree/master)

you should definatly write the developers that their site delivers server error and if you have the script you should host the file on your own